# Jackson json format date serialize even after setting Timezone

Tags: javascript, java, date, jackson

I am trying to serialize Date object sent as a javascript Date object in an ajax request. The date appears a day earlier than what is being sent from the client side. I figured this is because jackson Json sets default timezone to UTC.

```
 @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="mm-dd-yyyy",timezone="CET")
```

I have set the timezones to EST , Americas/New york and nothing seems to make me get the correct date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because of typo in the date format, we need to change it from

`@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="mm-dd-yyyy",timezone="CET")`

to

`@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM-dd-yyyy",timezone="CET")`

i.e. MM vs mm.

The below works fine for me:

```
class Model{

    @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM-dd-yyyy",timezone="CET")
    private Date date;

    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param date the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setDate(new Date());

        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(model));
    }
```

Comment: Wow . I did not even notice that. Thanks a lot ! i feel so dumb now. lol